# How do i configure an Upstart script to run prior to allowing user login?

Tags: upstart

As part of a system-provisioning process for Ubuntu 14.04, I would like to prevent user logins until my script has completed. I have an upstart job with the following contents:

```
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
stop on [!12345]

script
    #launch the bash script that does install
    /bin/bash /path/to/provisioning-script.sh
end script
```

This script runs at startup, but it does not prevent users from logging in. I have also tried the start directive

```
start on starting lightdm
```

But:

1. it doesn't prevent logins
2. applies only to systems using lightdm. Some of our systems boot to command line only

I have achieved the results I want in ubuntu 16.04 (systemd) with the following code:

```
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no
After=network.target
Before=systemd-user-sessions.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash /path/to/provisioning-script.sh
StandardOutput=journal+console
StandardError=journal+console

[Install]
RequiredBy=systemd-user-sessions.service
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered the first part of the question. Instead of running the script in the `started` phase of the service, I want to run it in the `prestart` phase. To so this, I needed to add `prestart` in front of the script tag.

Essentially, the result is that the service is not considered `started` until the `prestart` commands are complete, and the lightdm service won't start until my service is `started`.

```
start on starting lightdm
stop on [!12345]

prestart script
    #launch the bash script that does install
    /bin/bash /path/to/provisioning-script.sh
end script
```